Weight of an AC/DC transformer and wattage
You know those basic AC/DC adapter that come with every small appliance? What's the real map of the current technology/capacity? Averages, ballparks, IME allowed.
For example, I have plenty of 110V AC to 12 DC adapters. Most are in the 1-2 A capacity out. Branded quality adapters by Linksys or other "trusted" brands are quite heavy. 1 lbs or near.
Today I tested a package that had input 100-240 V 50/60 Hz, 0.7 A in max. output 12 V with 3 A out. It weighs 128 grams, including its 6 foot plug.
How is this possible? How over-engineered are brand-named transformers. This new transformer isn't using GaN technology or anything sophisticated. I don't believe the basic design had changed.
If this is too big for a single question, I'd like to make a repo about the weight of the transformers, their weight and output capacity and the potential danger involved in less heavy designs. Your experiences/insight. (IMO PSUs are too mysterious voodoo. We need a templar to clean it up).

What does "the real map of the current technology/capacity" mean? || Also, if it outputs DC, it's not a transformer. It has a transformer in it, probably, but it's a power converter in general--not a transformer.

I don't believe the basic design had changed. ... this may be a false assumption ... what time span are you talking about

You should include ore details, like how old are those "transformers" and adapters you are talking about, how big, how heavy, include some pictures of either or both the overall supply and the PCB. The way your question is worded, we are not sure whether adapter, transformer and power supply mean the same thing to you (and they are not the same thing), and what exactly are we talking about. You need to elaborate a bit more.

Anything is possible as long as you are willing to pay for it. Different transformers use differrent technologies and topologies even if they are rated for same voltage and current, because in some scenario some technology is more suitable. Comparing with cars, you can make different weight and size cars that go equally fast and accelerate at equal rate, (gasoline, diesel, EC) but you still choose a pickup truck, van or passenger car depending on what you want to achieve and at what price. E.g. use switch mode supply if you want light and a lot of noisy current, use a linear supply for audio.


PSUs are too mysterious voodoo. We need a templar to clean it up || ??


both really cheap and really expensive wall worts are light weight. I'm guessing your's is the former.

I have a 66W USB (with PD) credit-card size (and about 10mm thin- including fold-out US/China style blades) supply that weighs 62g. Most of the changes have been evolutionary, but they sure do add up.
This is maybe a 10 year difference - both supplies- the Dell and the Huawei- have the same ~66W rating (the weight difference is 4:1 and the volume is more than 5:1):

The block diagram would look similar between the older and more modern supplies, but virtually all the parts have improved. That allows more efficient circuits that switch much faster, allowing much, much smaller magnetics and much smaller output filters. That includes things like GaN transistors, faster diodes, high value MLCC capacitors, better ferrites, smaller connectors, and cheaper MOSFETs that allow things like synchronous rectification.
Probably the main remaining limitation is the mains reservoir capacitors which have to hold the energy required to maintain output in a single-phase input system. Electrolytic capacitors have progressed too, getting much smaller over time.
Of course it's always possible that the specs are not realistic for some no-name supply, but if it came with an appliance that has proper safety approvals that won't likely be the case.
BTW, one way to make the supply a bit smaller is to compromise on the input voltage range and make it 120V +/- or 240V +/- rather than universal. That allows the input reservoir capacitors to be almost half the volume, among other things. You can also make the whole thing less efficient meaning it will have to be larger to get rid of the heat.
If you use ordinary magnet wire for the transformer, the size will tend to be larger and a bit heavier for the same output power because you'll need a lot of tape and room for the tape to get the appropriate creepage. If you use a small core and ordinary magnet wire you can recover the size at the cost of safety (but then it will not pass safety testing).
For further comparison with even older technology, here is an old-school linear power supply model HN12-5.1-A+G with similar DC output power (12V @ 5.1 or about 61W):


Although it lacks a full housing and input/output connectors you can see the total volume is approximately 50x the most modern unit above, and the weight ratio is about the same. This is the kind of commercial open-frame power supply a designer might reach for ca. 1975, before the proliferation of computation devices in the 1980s such as the Apple II and IBM PC brought switching supplies to the masses. Earlier consumer computers such as S-100 (IMSAI, Chromemco etc.), Apple I, and Commodore PET used linear supplies.

Nice comparison. Including an old-school 66W laminated-iron transformer version would be even more dramatic.

@glen_geek Good idea, done.

There are generally two approaches to these products.
A 'transformer' one will generally only work on 110-120 V (or 220-240 V) and operate at 50 or 60 Hz. These are older, simpler (much less electronics; maybe just a bridge rectifier and a capacitor), and as you note quite heavy. Most are quite robust and could be expected to last a long time (10+ years). These do not have Power Factor Correction, and are deprecated (or disallowed) in some regions.
A 'power converter' can be much smaller. It uses a high frequency transformer (100's of kHz), and some moderately complex electronics to basically 'chop' the mains AC power into smaller chunks and send over the HF transformer (there are many other aspects). The electronics in these are highly stressed and generally not as reliable as a simple transformer. However they operate from 90 to 250 V, and provide a very accurate and stable output, more efficiently than a low-cost transformer. Lower cost ones do not include as much margin for safety, and won't be as reliable as 'name brand' ones. These are the most commonly available ones now.

I believe the word you want is deprecated, not depreciated.

You have not included any more detail or pictures about the bigger and heavier power supplies/adapters, so it's not easy to give you a more accurate answer.
All I can tell you that the design over time has improved regarding both the active and passive components.
Capacitors alone have been made smaller over the years without losing performance and quality, some even improving it.
MOSFETs have consistently improved over the years, in their speed, reduction of on resistance and switching times, in other words in overall efficiency, while their packaging/casing was made smaller. You have mentioned GaN technology, which is yet another huge leap in efficiency, but you mention it's not used in the supply you have looked at. Are you sure?
Power supply IC controllers have increased in their complexity to allow for more efficient control schemes like higher frequencies, faster switching and inclusion of LLC topologies, along with reduced power requirements for controllers themselves, including standby power consumption. Many of them include high voltage power MOSFETs inside them.
Ferrite core transformers have improved cores which provide higher efficiency at higher frequencies, which is the main reason for transformer size reduction.
As you probably know, the higher the frequency at which a transformer can operate, the smaller its core and the shorter its wire (fewer turns of wire needed) which in itself reduces wire losses.
Any transformer core, whether iron or ferrite, has higher losses at higher frequencies, but special materials allow much higher frequencies with low losses, thus allowing smaller transformers.
As for your question regarding "over-engineering", I am not sure what you mean by that. The term "over-engineered" refers to a device which has been made much better than it needs to be, whether its withstand voltage is far above the expected voltages, its power or current capabilities significantly higher than needed, its maximum working temperature much higher than the actual one, etc.  Your understanding of that word may be different, but over-engineering is almost always better for the end user in terms getting higher quality, reliability and longer life.
You may have meant to say their size was reduced too much to make them safe, reliable or long-lasting.
